# this.stlLoader.loadAsync is not a function

Tags: angular, stl

angular-stl-model-viewer throws an error I do not understand:

```
zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: this.stlLoader.loadAsync is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this.stlLoader.loadAsync is not a function
```

[Error code][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLCZJ.png

I installed angular-stl-model-viewer with npm and imported StlModelViewerModule to my app module, then I only added this to my html: `<stl-model-viewer [stlModels]="['example.stl']"></stl-model-viewer>`

So I pretty much only did, what the documentation tells me to do.